# how to solve watermark when exporting pages into images using (master pdf editor 5)

Tags: command-line, pdf, master-pdf-editor

when I want to export a page into an image using master pdf editor 5 it does export the specific image with text written on the top left corner saying (Master PDF Editor-Demo Version) so how to remove this text?
see the picture provided:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtUrf.png)

Comment: Obviously the software you are talking about is not free and open source. You have to pay for it.

Answer (score 3):

It’s pretty simple, really:

1. Visit [the developer’s website](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/)
2. Buy a license for $69.95
3. Apply the license to your installation

Shouldn’t take more than 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result with the help different tools:

## `pdfjam`

> The pdfjam package for manipulating PDF files

[pdfjam](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam)

```bsh
$ pdfjam --nup 2x2 in.pdf --outfile out.pdf
```

## jPDF Tweak

or if you prefer to work with a GUI:

> jPDF Tweak is a Java Swing application that can combine, split, rotate, reorder, watermark, encrypt, sign, and otherwise tweak PDF files.

[jPDF Tweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/) can help you customize layout of your PDF file.

## `pdftppm`

> pdftoppm - Portable Document Format (PDF) to Portable Pixmap (PPM) converter

Convert the newly generated PDF into a series of images using `pdftopptm`.

```bsh
$ pdftoppm -png <pdf_name> <image_name_prefix>
```

ref: https://superuser.com/a/246261/